# library not found for -lProtobuf in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode10.2.1

I'm using Xcode 10.2.1 and objective-c in my project. after using this commond in terminal:

```
git checkout "specific commit"
```

I'm bring back my codes to 4 month ago. after using this command in terminal I must change Bundle Identifier (because I'm no longer have access to that developer account).

after that I'm getting this error in Xcode (before that I'm getting error about account, No account for team "*****".):

```
library not found for -lProtobuf
```

I tried to delete pod file and reinstall pods by run this command in terminal:

```
pod install
```

but the problem not solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your project from its `.xcworkspace` file instead of `.xcodeproj` file.

Comment: After using pods in my project from the beginning, I’m always opening my project from it’s .xcworkspace file